# Eclipse: How can I see the file structure?

Tags: eclipse, intellij-idea, keyboard-shortcuts

I have been using IntelliJ till now and have switch to Eclipse because reasons.
In **IntelliJ**, I can see the file structure by <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>F12</kbd>. It pops ups something like this:

[image]

How do I get a similar thing in **Eclipse**?

Comment: Try with `CMD + O`/`CTRL + O` (Outline)

Answer (score 1):

Based on your image, I don't think you are looking for the directory structure but rather the code outline which shows things like classes, variables, and methods.

[image]

This is found in the following menu: `Window-> Show View -> Outline`

[image]

If you are looking for the directory structure, the `package explorer` on the lefthand side will show you your project. It might be minimized, the icon is 2 small boxes one on top of each other like so: 
[image]

click on that and it will show you the workspace.